# Does there exist a live-cd of Windows 7 or 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, livecd, windows-pe

I know there a few Windows live-cd's that were based on Windows PE. But does there exist a live-cd of the normal Windows too?

Comment: nope. You can use this project to get a GUI: http://w7pese.cwcodes.net/, http://w8pese.cwcodes.net/, http://win81se.cwcodes.net/

Comment: What you describe is a feature of `Windows 8.1 Enterprise` known as `Windows To Go` there are various third-party projects that come close ( and they are not WinPE ).  If you don't have a license to `Windows 8.1 Enterprise` then you wouldn't have access to `Windows To Go`.  There isn't a `Windows 7` version of `Windows To Go`

Comment: From USB interesting [link here](http://betanews.com/2014/01/13/run-windows-8-or-8-1-directly-from-a-usb-drive-on-any-computer-for-free/) OT: for all the ones will arrive to this page searching for other versions too there is a [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_live_CDs) with the list of live CDs